# Float div left and button right

Tags: html, css

*Please note: I have looked at several SO posts and various suggestions for floating 2 divs side by side, however none of them seemed to work for me.*

A summary of suggestions are:

```
display: inline-block
float: left
```

others refer to `overflow: hidden`, `overflow: auto` with various implementations.

One had worked, required me to set the right `div`:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px
```

This was undesireable since the button would attach itself the the right side, ignoring all parent container constraints.

[image]

Above is that what I want to achieve.

The *left* div has the blue background. The *right* div contains the button.

**My code:**

Html

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="display-inline-block float-left">
                    <h1>Your Order Schedule
                        <a id="editScheduleName" onclick="changeScheduleName()">
                            <img class="schedule-heading small-image" src=""images/icons/edit.png">
                        </a>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="display-inline-block float-right">
                    <input id="btnScheduleStatus" type="button" class="btn button-status btn-success" value="my button">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Css
*Note:using a basis of bootstrap for most of my css needs*

```
.display-inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
}

.schedule-heading {
    position: relative;
}

.small-image {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button-status {
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Check out CSS `flexboxes`; `display: flex; justify-content: space-between` might solve your problem.

Comment: your row should be of 100% width and the child divs of 50% both then apply float left. `.row{width:100%} .display-inline-block{width:50%, float:left}` and don't forget flex is also a better option as suggested by Nandu Kalidindi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any changes to css, purely using bootstrap:

Few key things: ensure you add columns (`<div class="col-md-12">`) after specifying `<div class="row">`

You can use the `pull-left` & `pull-right` classes to float the content:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><!-- define columns in bootstrap -->
        <div class="pull-left"><!-- use pull-left -->
            <h1>
                Your Order Schedule
                <a id="editScheduleName" onclick="changeScheduleName()">
                    <img class="schedule-heading small-image" src="images/icons/edit.png">
                </a>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right"><!-- use pull-right -->
            <input id="btnScheduleStatus" type="button" class="btn button-status btn-success" value="my button">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kedekdoc/)

This has better overall browser support than `display:flex` which is not supported in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.display-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.schedule-heading {
  position: relative;
}

.small-image {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button-status {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="display-inline-block float-left">
    <h1>Your Order Schedule
      <a id="editScheduleName" onclick="changeScheduleName()">
                            <img class="schedule-heading small-image" src="images/icons/edit.png"/>
                        </a>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="display-inline-block float-right">
    <input id="btnScheduleStatus" type="button" class="btn button-status btn-success" value="my button">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Try to use `display: flex`!

You can search in Google, you can learn `display: flex` easily.

Comment: firstly thank you for the rapid response. I have come accross using flex, although I forgot to mention it. The issue with flex was, using it in the parent div where the left and right divs were children, the left div displayed as required, but the button was floating left in the presence of `float-right`. I shall implement your suggestion now

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a container div for both your buttons, and then have them inside as 2 divs. Then you can write in your CSS:

```
.button_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

}
```

You don't need to write anything for the other 2 divs.